# Trigger based on record type to show the result as

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

Here I want to show if we select the status as 'offer letter' then triggered out 'hired' in record type or else 'not hired'.

```
trigger trg_update_recordstatus on positions__c (before insert,before update) {

    for(positions__c pos:trigger.new){
        recordtype__c[] rectype;
        rectype=[SELECT id,status FROM positions__c WHERE Position_Status__c='offer letter'];  
        if(Pos.Position_Status__c='offer letter'){
        Pos.rectype='hired';
        else
        Pos.rectype='not hired';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to update the RecordTypeId?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a matter of assigning a record type based on the value of a picklist, a far better solution would be to create a workflow rule with a field update action to assign record type.

This is a great use case for config before code.

[image]

Comment: I'm beginner for this trigger concepts to generate codes so that only i'm trying to learn in record types.. Is it possible to generate through record types know...

Comment: Can you help me understand better? You are using this trigger example as practice to learn how to write Apex code? Is that what you mean by "generate" code? If that is the case, there might be better use cases to learn from as record type is a bit tricky. I certainly wouldn't put code like this in production due to the ease of the declarative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear if you are talking about Record Types or you have some custom object you call recordtype__c.  I'm going to assume you are talking about standard Salesforce RecordTypes.

You need to get the Record Type Id for each record type.  You could have a custom setting that holds these, but to use the code you already have I would just create a map with the record type Ids.

Something like this should work

```
trigger trg_update_recordstatus on positions__c (before insert,before update) {

     map<string,Id> recordTypeMap = new map<string,Id>();
     list<RecordType> recTypes = [Select Id, Name From RecordType Where sObjectType = 'positions__c' and isActive = true ];
     for(RecordType rt : recTypes){
         recordTypeMap.put(rt.Name, rt.Id);
     }
     for(positions__c pos : trigger.new){     
          if(pos.Position_Status__c='offer letter'){
                //You would use whatever record type name you are looking for
                Pos.RecordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get('Hired');
          }else{
                Pos.RecordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get('Not Hired');
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dunc44 there is one correctable flaw in your solution. RecordType stores record types for *all* objects. The record type name "Hired" could exist for two different objects in which case you would not be guaranteed to get the correct record type Id in the map you create. I would suggest refining your query to search for the correct sObjectType and isActive=true.

Comment: @Peter, great point.  updated the code to reflect.  Nice catch.  Thanks